# Enumerate does not put dots after characters

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I'm using

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*] 
{
 \item blah blah blah
}
```

and I'm using Arabic language for my paper. but, the enumerate does not put "dots" after the characters, it shows:

```
آ blah blah blah
```

instead of

```
آ. blah blah blah
```

so, How can I force it to use "dots" after the beginning characters?

Comment: please always post complete examples. There should be no `{...}` around `\item`  also you seem to be using (but do not say) `enumitem` package syntax. You can add `.` or any other characters to the label after `\alph*`

Answer (score 3):

An example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item $x=1$
\item $y=2$
\item $z=3$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```